# How to hide all my logs when users use my android app?

Tags: android, debugging, tags, logging

My boss hopes that there is no information leak when users use our android apps.
And I found even I set the `android:debuggable="false"` it still can see my logs from Logcat or command line.
I searched android:debuggable someone also have the same problem.
I got some answers from internet, such as next:

> There are a property called debugable of Avd. You can print by adb
> shell  get prop. I don't (know) if it is the cause of your problem.
>
> If you have a pre-production device, you
> can still debug an app that has debuggable set to false.

I just think, even I delete all my logs, there are also many logs about my app from OS.

My questions:
1.Is there a way I can do let my "android:debuggable" work well and
2.Is there any other way to hide all my logs except delete all my logs?
3.What does "android:debuggable" really mean?
4.What is "a pre-production device" when it goes on android device?

Thank you for your help. I will try some other ways, and try my best to share my information in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply create wrapper functions around `Log` that first check the value of a `static boolean` called `loggineEnabled` if it is set to true then log gets called otherwise the calls to log are ignored.

Then I simply set this variable to false before I compile a version of my app that I distribute.

```
void LogD(String msg){
   if (loggingEnabled)
       Log.d(MyTag, msg)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Is your code guaranteed to be bug-free? If not, why do you want to stop users having information that they might be able to use to shed light on bugs in your app?

Come back when you can write bug-free code, then we’ll talk.

Comment: I think my boss doesn't like to let use know our debug information. And why he doesn't like, I think it's just because the company doesn't like. And thank you for your information, I will tell my boss your opinion.

Comment: Logcat messages are of almost no value to the end user.  The correct thing to do is to suppress log messages for the distributed version of your app.  Additionally trying to debug your own app while another app hasn't suppressed their log messages is a real pain.

Comment: Who says they’re supposed to be useful to the user? The point is, the user can copy and paste them into a bug report, for the developer to look at. Developers on their own are never going to be able to reproduce all the possible conditions under which users run their software.